# Using Magento Collections with External DB

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I'm trying to access data on a external DB from magento from a Module, while using Magento ORM capabilites, I was able to do so by extending the:

Mage_Core_Model_Abstract and Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract classes as shown on this page:

http://www.solvingmagento.com/accessing-an-external-database-from-your-magento-module/

However when I'm try to use the getCollection() method on my model and I get "false" so I'm wondering if you can create collections based on the "Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract" class, I tried with "Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract" without any luck.

If it's not possible, does that mean that I have to change my module and use:

Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract instead of Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract

As it seems like it has a "Mage_Core_Model_Mysq4_Collection_Abstract" class that works for what I want to do, as shown in:

http://fishpig.co.uk/magento/tutorials/create-external-database-connection/

I was trying to avoid Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract as it sounds to me that it's exclusive for MySQL and I was hoping to keep the code more flexible.

Thanks,

Comment: Do you want to be able to read only or read and write to this external db ?

Comment: Read and write. It seems like I can do so using  Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract, my problem is that I can't create collections.

Comment: Can you paste the xml for the module ?

Comment: @Ox3, did you fix this? I've got the same issue with the prefix.

Comment: @Ricky: yes, use Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract and Mage_Core_Model_Mysq4_Collection_Abstract as suggested in: http://fishpig.co.uk/magento/tutorials/create-external-database-connection/